# Crontab executes only first line

Tags: shell, centos, cron

I'm trying to setup several cron jobs on VPS under centos/whm.
I've added to /var/spool/cron/root following lines:

```
*/5 * * * * find /some-dir/* \( ! -iname ".ht*" \) -delete
*/10 * * * * find /some-other-dir/* \( ! -iname ".ht*" \) -delete
```

but only the first line executed ( for /some-dir/). If I swap lines - /some-other-dir/ executed, /some-dir/ - not. I've tried to put semicolons at the end of each line, to put spaces, tabs, change file encoding - nothing.

How can I make cron process both tasks?

here is the /var/log/cron output:

```
Sep 18 11:05:01 host crond[3302]: (root) CMD (find /some-dir/* \( ! -iname ".ht*" \) -delete)
Sep 18 11:10:01 host crond[3303]: (root) RELOAD (/var/spool/cron/root)
```

thanks!

Comment: Tried to put the complete command in round brackets i.e. `* * * * * (complete command)` and check

Comment: same result - only first line works

Comment: Is the crontab entries correctly updated? Looking at your /var/log/cron output, it seems there was no command at the 10th minute to run.

Comment: Yes, exactly - it's reloading when trying run second line. no matter of lines order. and I can't figure why - if it was syntax error, why first line is OK no matter of line contents?

Comment: Cron expects a command to take less than one minute to finish.  You can try forking it by adding a & at the end of the command.

Comment: thanks, but same result. will try to use this commands within a script

Comment: Wonder if your `crond` doesn't support running two commands simultaneously -- try making them run at different times (e.g. 31,33,35,37 for one and 32,34,36,38 for the other)

Comment: I tried simple `mail -s "test" me@host.com` instead of `find` and it worked ok. so the problem is in the find command? Also, both commands worked fine from a shell script by cron.

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference, but are you directly editing the crontab files or are you using the `crontab` command to do it?

Comment: I'm editing directly, however, I tried `crontab -e` too

Answer (score 6):

It seems like cron requires an empty line an the end of crontab. I accidentally left such line and viola! both tasks executed.