# Cron is not able to execute python script

Tags: python, cron

working on windows 10 using putty. I want to schedule a task using cron but its not working for the python code(sowfinal.py) which I want to run but I am to execute a simple python code(sowtest.py)... is it because of the libraries I am using ?

```
** * * * cd home/db2inst1/TicketAnalytics /usr/local/bin/python sowtest.py  /tmp/listener.log 2>&1

** * * * cd home/db2inst1/TicketAnalytics /usr/local/bin/python sowfinal.py  /tmp/listener.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Try adding a `;` after the `cd` command.  Or get rid of the `cd` in general (like @Rakesh proposed), but that might involve adjusting your script.  Some scripts depend on their work dir.

Comment: its working for the sowtest.py file but not for the other file(sowfinal.py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without cd

```
** * * * /usr/local/bin/python /home/db2inst1/TicketAnalytics/sowtest.py /tmp/listener.log 2>&1

** * * * /usr/local/bin/python /home/db2inst1/TicketAnalytics/sowfinal.py /tmp/listener.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Probably there is an issue with the way cron job is configured. Can you try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479973/crontab-executes-only-first-line

Comment: Also try adding ";" at the end of the first job.